# get Height Value from NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

In my project I am using AutoLayOut, There is one UIView which is subView main View, I have set its width(using constrains) equal to 2 :3 superView's width and its height equal to its View. I need view to be circular shape so I am setting its cornerRadius to heightOfView/2. There is 1:1 aspect ration of views's height and width. I have created Outlet of that constrain as

```
 @IBOutlet weak var circleHeight: NSLayoutConstraint
```

Now I want to acces its Height or Width but I m not gwtting actual value,

```
circleHeight.firstItem.frame.width
```

I am getting value which I have stored from Storyboard, There Is something I am Missing but could not figured it out

[image]
Selected View should be circular. but when i print its constain's values it gives height and width as 214 only

Comment: it can change, so you need to update the radius when the frame changes, which is when subviews / sublayers are laid out.

Comment: but Frame's Values is not changing

Comment: Where/when are you accessing the frame? As Wain says, they may change when the layout engine is triggered. Also, the image shows a constraint violation at the bottom - perhaps this is preventing your layout from working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you might be fetching value in `viewWillAppear` or
   `ViewDidLoad` but views frames don't get updated when these method gets
   called
2. So you need to fetch the width or height in `ViewDidAppear` method.
3. If get the height or width in `ViewDidLayoutSubViews`, performance
   gets degraded as it gets called many times.

Here is Code

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       let viewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(yourView.frame)
       yourView.layer.cornerRadius = viewHeight / 2
       yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create IBOutlet for this UIView, which should be circle shape.
Then in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method you can read its height and make it circle:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let viewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(yourView.frame)
    yourView.layer.cornerRadius = viewHeight / 2
    yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constraint does not have height or width, only relationships, priorities and constant values, depending in how you set the constraint itself.

To access the height of the subview you are interested in, you need to access as always:

```
<uiview_outlet>.frame.size.height
```

Hope it helps.